# Approximated TSP: weight of minimum spanning tree less than cost of the optimal tour?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, traveling-salesman, approximation-algorithms

In the chapter, *Approximation Algorithms* of *Introduction to Algorithm, 3rd Edition*, for the approximation problem **Travelling Salesman Problem**, the author proposes a approximation method that first constructs a minimum spanning tree.

[image]

In order to prove this algorithm is a 2-approximation algorithm, the author claims that:

The weight of the minimum spanning tree $T$ is less than the cost of the optimal tour.

I am wondering if the minimum spanning tree(which is **acyclic**) of $G$ ensures that its weight is **necessarily** smaller than any tour(which is **cyclic**) of the same graph $G$

PS:

The original claim is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you take any tour and remove any edge, then you get a spanning tree. Hence the weight of a minimum spanning tree is at most the weight of every tour.

I should add that one of the tricks behind this algorithm is that while we can't find a minimum tour efficiently, we can find a minimum spanning tree. Minimum spanning tree is an efficiently computable relaxation of minimum Hamiltonian path.